# How to check if string (fully or partly) matches values on all columns of dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I have a dataframe:

```
x1               x2 
value           12
john and bob    45
another         87
```

I want to check if there is string "bob" among all values. I want function which will take dataframe and string name and will return TRUE for this dataframe. `apply(df, 1, function(r) any(r == "bob"))` requires full match, so it doesn't work this for example:

```
x1               x2 
value           12
johnandbob      45
another         87
```

Also it returns TRUE\FALSE for each value in dataframe, so if I have million values there will be million TRUE\FALSE. However I need only one is there necessary value among them or not. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `grepl` for partial matching and `any` to get only one value.

```
any(grepl('bob', df$x1))
#[1] TRUE
```

This will also return `TRUE` for values like `'bobby'`, `'ambob'` etc. If you want it to match exactly use word boundaries (`\\b`) around them.

```
any(grepl('\\bbob\\b', df$x1))
```

Comment: thanks, and will it stop searching once it found one? or it will check all them? i have dataframe with dozens of millions rows and many columns, so I need algorithm which will stop searching once it found one match. otherwise it will take hours

Comment: Well, R is a vectorised language. So functions like `grepl` work on entire column at once. You can write a `for` loop to do this one by one and stop when you find the string but that is going to be so much inefficient than the current answer. If this solution is really slow then you may need to write the loop in `Rcpp` which might make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

We could use `str_detect` from `stringr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(across(everything(), ~str_detect(., "bob")))
```

Output:

```
  x1    x2   
  <lgl> <lgl>
1 FALSE FALSE
2 TRUE  FALSE
3 FALSE FALSE
```

Or for one column of a `df`

```
any(str_detect(df$x1, "bob"))
```

Output:

```
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, and will it stop searching once it found one? or it will check all them? i have dataframe with dozens of millions rows and many columns, so I need algorithm which will stop searching once it found one match. otherwise it will take hours

Comment: Try this `library(stringi)
stri_match_first_regex(df1$x1, "bob")`